# I cannot migrate database in Laravel . it says SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out

Tags: laravel

**These are related images          **

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAE1i.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJGIR.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBLkW.png

Comment: Don't post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)!

Answer (score -1):

Why in .env DB_HOST=27.0.0.1 ?  Maybe 127.0.0.1 works better ?